# How accurate and reliable is loudness analysis (ebur128) in ffmpeg for PCM?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pcm

I need to test a lot of files on possible audio normalization issues, files can be of various containers and audio encoding formats but mostly PCM audio. I tried Rhozet QC solution but found it unreliable, it could easily skip short loud spikes so now I'm looking at ffmpeg.

I tested it and it looks ok-ish but does anyone have any experience with such tasks? Can I trust ffmpeg with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EBU provides a set of [sample PCM audio files](https://tech.ebu.ch/publications/ebu_loudness_test_set) to audit loudness measuring equipment. Based on testing a few random files from the set, ffmpeg's EBU R128 analyzer passes. But you may want to do a thorough survey.

Result for `1kHz Sine -20 LUFS-16bit.wav`

```
  Integrated loudness:
    I:         -20.0 LUFS
    Threshold: -30.0 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:         0.0 LU
    Threshold: -40.0 LUFS
    LRA low:   -20.0 LUFS
    LRA high:  -20.0 LUFS
```

Result for `1kHz Sine -26 LUFS-16bit.wav`

```
  Integrated loudness:
    I:         -26.0 LUFS
    Threshold: -36.0 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:         0.0 LU
    Threshold: -46.0 LUFS
    LRA low:   -26.0 LUFS
    LRA high:  -26.0 LUFS
```